# How to do Angular 2 project with DevExtreme using Visual Studio 2017/2015

Tags: visual-studio, angular, devextreme

**Can any one explain me how to do Angular 2 project with DevExtreme control using Visual Studio 2017/2015**. I want to use the control shown here-https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Scheduler/Timelines/Angular/Light/..
Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Visual studio solution, for example by following the tutorial here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/ .
use npm to install devextreme and you're ready to create the devextreme controls.

Comment: Getting **.Net Core SDK not found.** error. I installed the required file also, but anyway I'm getting error. Is there any solution...